# What does 'ODS' stand for in database context?

Tags: database

In database context, what does `ODS` stand for? Many times I saw it used as opposed to `OLTP`, I know what `OLTP` is, but I don't know `ODS`. Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two definitions. One for Online Decision Support (aka DSS) and one for Operational Data Store. I assume that your references are to the first since it was contrasted against OLTP

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933056(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

ODS = Operational Data Store. Check this link: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/ODS.html

Answer (score 1):

ODS stands for Open Document Spreadsheet